# How to create an RegEx that rejects double slash but accept the String if there is a word between?

Tags: regex

My goal is to reject these input

Appendix A.

```
//www.example.com
http://www.example.com//
```

and match these input, Appendix B.

```
http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
```

My current RegEx is `(\/[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)*`. Edit: I changed it and make it verbose `(/[a-zA-Z0-9.]+[a-zA-Z0-9./]+)`. Am I doing it right?

My expected result is that the regex reject the Appendix A. and match the Appendix B.

My actual result is that the regex only group this part while the last `/` is not grouped, and adding `/` to the brackets only will make the regex did not reject the Appendix A.

```
/pub/ietf/uri
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to discern exactly what you want here, but if you want to avoid double slashes at the beginning or end of the string, you could use a couple negative lookarounds:

"don't see double slash at start of string, match some stuff, look back to make sure we don't see double slash at end of string"

```
^(?!//).*(?<!//)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/zdlMvk/1/